# number of parameters of $SO(3)$ group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

The $SO(3)$ rotation group is defined by:

$A\cdot A^T=\mathbb{1}$ and $\det{A}=1$. The group is supposed to have 3 free parameters, as suggested by Euler's angles. However, I am doing something wrong with counting of the parameters because I cannot arrive at that number.

$3\times3$ matrix has $9$ free parameters. The requirement $A\cdot A^T=\mathbb{1}$ produces 6 equations for those parameters:
$$
\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{a_1}=1\\
\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{a_2}=0\\
\vec{a_1}\cdot\vec{a_3}=0\\
\vec{a_2}\cdot\vec{a_2}=1\\
\vec{a_2}\cdot\vec{a_3}=0\\
\vec{a_3}\cdot\vec{a_3}=1\\
$$

($\vec{a_i}$ being the columns of $A$) and reduces the number of free parameters to 3. But with this requirement $\det{A}=\pm 1$ and so $\det{A}=1$ presents another restricting euqation, and so i get 2 free parameters.

If I do a similar counting for the $SU(2)$ group, i have 8 free parameters of $2\times2$ complex matrix, the requirement $A\cdot A^\dagger=\mathbb{1}$ provides 4 independent equations and the determinant provides 2 more conditions (complex and imaginary parts) which again reduces to only 2 free parameters.

Where am i doing the mistake in counting the parameters and equations?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the restriction $\det A=1$ does *not* lead to a reduction on the number of parameters. Consider, for instance, $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. It is $1$-dimensional. And if consider the subset $\{x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\mid\operatorname{sgn}(x)=1\}$, then you still have a $1$-dimensional thing.

It is similar here: $O(3,\Bbb R)$ is $3$-dimensional and $SO(3,\Bbb R)$, which is one-half of it, is still $3$-dimensional.

Comment: I am not sure about what you write as you talk about dimensions-euler angles cannot generate all members of $O(3,\mathbb{R})$, that needs additional parameters. I also corrected the counting for $SU(2)$ which does not work either now. From a different perspective: $3x3$ matrix has $9$ coefficients, the orthonormality provides 6 linearly independent conditions on those coefficients, so that you can only freely choose 3 and finally, determinant is just another equation, independent of the other 6, and thus you have 9 parameters and 7 equations that tie them up. This i would like explained.

Comment: The determinant being one just cuts the space in half (the determinant of every orthogonal matrix is $\pm1$). And half of a $n$-dimensional thing is still a $n$-dimensional thing.

Comment: We might be talking about different things. Do you agree that for a general $3\times3$ matrix, you need to specify $9$ parameters (but they are still "3 dimensional things", no?)? How about a group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ ($2\times2$ complex matrices with unit determinant), one says that the group has 6 parameters, because one has 8 numbers to specify the matrix and the determinant provides 2 conditions. Eg. there is no isomorphism between $SO(3)$ and $O(3)$ (both "3-d things") but there is one between $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ (both not "3-d things" but same amount of parameters).

Comment: Concerning your first question: no. The space of $3\times3$ matrices is $9$-dimensional, not $3$-dimensional.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that $SO(3)$ and $SU(2)$ are not isomorphic. In fact, both $O(3)$ and $SU(2)$ have a two-to-one correspondence with $SO(3)$, meaning all three are 'six dimensional objects'.

Answer (score 1):

You have a $9$-dimensional space with coordinates $\{(a_{11},a_{12},\dots,a_{33})|A=(a_{ij})\}$ which are restricted exactly to those 6 equations that you wrote. If a point $x$ satisfy those equations then a point $y=-x$ also satisfy them since

$$(-a_1)\cdot (-a_1)=1$$
$$(-a_1)\cdot (-a_2)=0$$
$$(-a_1)\cdot (-a_3)=0$$
$$(-a_2)\cdot (-a_2)=1$$
$$(-a_2)\cdot (-a_3)=0$$
$$(-a_3)\cdot (-a_3)=1$$
i.e. $x$ and $-x$ belong to your hypersurface.

But in terms of the determinant, you just change the sign of it since 
$$det(-A)=(-1)^3det(A)=-det(A)$$
since $A$ is $3\times 3$ matrix.

So, as was said before, you just take a half of your hypersurface by setting the restriction $det(A)=1$.

Comment: That is a good explanation. I think I understand what you are saying. But from a different perspective, does that mean that if you write out $\det{A}$ as $\sum_\sigma \mathrm{sgn}(\sigma) \prod a_{i,\sigma(i)} = 1$ then this equation is not independent of those 6?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the fact that in $O(3)$, the determinant can assume only two values, $\pm1$. Therefore, fixing one of the two values ($SO(3)$) does not remove any free parameter, as it needs to remain continuous. On the other hand, in $U(2)$, the determinant is a free parameter (with magnitude 1, but being a complex number, is continuous). Consequently, $SU(2)$ does indeed fix a free parameter.